# Can i use Transformer-XL for text classification task?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow, transformer, text-classification

I want to use transformer xl for text classification tasks. But I don't know the architect model for the text classification task. I use dense layers with activation softmax for logits output from the transformer xl model, but this doesn't seem right. when training I see accuracy is very low.

Output of my model:

[image: output, logits transformer-xl]

My training step:

[image: dense layer]

Comment: Classification with Transformer XL should be similar to classification with BERT, you must be doing something wrong. (But bidirectional models like BERT or RoBERTa might be a better choice because they are bidirectional.) Can you provide more details? What exactly do you use as input to the classifier?

Comment: @Jindřich I'm using IMDb dataset. and input is data was tokenizer